# Does .NET event-based asynchronous pattern for I/O operation blocked threads in underlying?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool

In typical .NET world, we use event-based asynchronous pattern(Event Handler) for most I/O operations, more specific as I know, the I/O completion port was introduced for improve the efficiency of scheduling the threads, like the ThreadPool, thus we don't need to manually maintain(init and destroy) the threads to handle the massive I/O responses.

Meanwhile, I naturally thought the waiting for I/O response don't need block any thread in modern Windows system because of hardware interrupt until I saw some pieces of C++ code in my recent project and even some sample code in web.

**I Don't have any C++ experience**

The first code piece is about a serial port listening, the pseudo C++ code(i input it in C# style) is like:

```
    // loop checking the status
    while(serialPort.Buffer.Count==0)
    {
          Thread.Sleep(100);
    }  

    byte[] data = serialPort.Buffer;
    // processing the actual data...
```

The second code piece is about the usage of I/O completion port in C++:

```
    while (::GetQueuedCompletionStatus(port,
                                       &bytesCopied,
                                       &completionKey,
                                       &overlapped,
                                       INFINITE))
    {
        if (0 == bytesCopied && 0 == completionKey && 0 == overlapped)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Process completion packet
        }
    }
```

Obviously, they all blocking the thread.

So my question are:

1. Why those code didn't choose the Event-based no thread blocking way?
2. If .NET underlying use the second sample's code, so actually there're threads blocked when doing I/O operations?
3. (May a little off topic) Does .NET I/O operation callback allow concurrently re-enter when previous callback still under executing?(from my limited tests, the answer is NO) and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first, blocking is not, in itself, bad.  The 'main' GUI thread in a Windows app fires its 'OnClick' etc. events in response to messages received from a Windows message queue - a blocking producer-consumer queue.  When no messages are received, the thread blocks on the queue. Same with most 'non-blocking' select() based servers - select is a blocking call,, (though it can be made to poll by setting a low/zero timeout - a poor design).

1)  Asynchronous designs are intrinsically more complex.  Per-socket context data, (eg. buffers), cannot be maintained in stack-based auto vars and must be maintained across events by either maintaining a global container of context objects, (that have to be looked up by socket handle in the events when they are fired), or by issuing context objects with the I/O requests and retrieving them from callback parameters in the events.  Asynchronous designs should be totally asynchronous - calling anything that might block for any extended period has to be avoided if possible.  Calls to opaque external libraries, DB queries and the like can be troublesome in this respect, blocking the supposedly asynchronous thread and preventing it from responding to events.

The first code snippet is just horrible and I struggle to find any justification for it at all. The sleep() loop polling has a built-in average 50ms latency in responding to input. Just mega-lame when better synch and async solutions exist.  A dedicated read thread, queued APCs, (completion routines) and IOCP are all available for serial ports.

The second code-snippet IS, effectively, event-based async. You could make it look even more 'event-based' by having the handler threads call an event-handler with the parameters returned by the completion message.

IOCP is the preferred high-performance I/O system for Windows.  It can handle many types of I/O operations and it's threadpool-based handlers can withstand occasional blocking or lengthy operations without holding up the processing of further I/O completions.  Passing user-buffers in with the call allows the driver/s to load them directly in kernel space and removes a layer of copying.  What it does not do is avoid the need to maintain context across the asynchronous calls.

Synchronous thread-per-client is commonly used where the requirements for scalability are swamped by the simple in-line code and immunity from blocking calls that are inherent in such designs.  Handling serial comms is not something where scalability to thousands of ports is ever an issue.

2) IOCP handler threads block while waiting for completion messages, sure.  If there is nothing to be done, threads should block:)

3) They should do.  Adding on an extra layer of signaling to ensure that the callbacks are handled serially involves more overhead and adds back in the vulnerability to any kind of blocking in the callback holding up the handling of other callbacks from other IOCP handler threads that would not need to block.  Since context is passed in as a parameter, there is no intrinsic requirement for IOCP-driven callbacks to be run in a serial manner.  The code in the callback handler can just operate on the passed information in the manner of a state-machine.

That said, I would not be surprised if MS .NET did indeed provide signaling/queueing to enforce serial, non-reeentrant callbacks.  Insufficiently experienced devs. often do things in multithreaded callbacks that they should not do, eg. accessing global/persistent state without any locking, or accessing thread-bound GUI controls directly.  Serializing the calls, either by wrapping them into Windows messages or otherwise, removes this risk at the expense of performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably because asynchronous programming is hard.
2. .Net, on an I/O method mostly exposes a synchronous operation and an asynchronous operation when it can. So for example you have `TcpClient.Connect` and `TcpClient.ConnectAsync`/`TcpClient.BeginConnect`. Whatever starts with "Begin" or ends with "Async" is at least supposed to be async, which means there are no blocked threads. `TcpClient.Connect` is blocking and hence less scalable.
3. I'm not really sure, but i think they can. The question is why you want to do that? And how can you match a callback with its call?